# C++ Copy Constructor and = operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, destructor, copy-constructor

I am trying to get my head around copy constructors, operator overloading and destructors in C++. Given a class which contains a pointer to it's own type, how would one write the copy constructors or = operator overload? I have attempted the following, but I keep getting segmentation faults when declaring or assigning Test objects in main. Could anyone explain what I am doing incorrectly?

```
class Test {
public:
    Test(string name);
    Test(const Test& testObject);
    Test& operator=(const Test& rhs);
    ~Test();
    string getName();
    void setName(string newname);
    Test* getNeighbor(int direction);
    void setNeighbor(Test* newTest, int direction);
private:
    string name;
    Test* neighbors[4];
};    

Test::Test() {
    name = "*";
    neighbors[4] = new Test[4];
}

Test::Test(const Test& testObject) {
    this->name = testObject.name;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        this->neighbors[i] = testObject.neighbors[i];
    }
}

Test& Test::operator=(const Test& rhs) {
    if (this == &rhs) {
        return *this;
    }
    else {
        name = rhs.name;
        delete [] neighbors;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            neighbors[i] = rhs.neighbors[i];
        }
        return *this;
    }
}
```

Comment: `neighbours` is an array. You can't `delete[]` an array.

Comment: So in this case would I simply just remove that line, or am I missing a key concept here?

Comment: I suppose, if nothing is dynamically allocated, but in that case, there's no point in overloading either.

Comment: Are the pointers in `neighbors[]` managed and owned by the `Test` instance? if so, you need proper RO3 implementation, and to avoid redundancy I would probably implement `Test& operator =(Test rhsCopy)` and use a copy-swap implementation. Then again, I'd likely use a `std::array<std::shared_ptr<Test>,4>` and make it moot regardless. If not (not owned by `Test`) then i see no reason for any of this.

Answer (score 0):

You should not delete `neighbors` as it is a static array. Instead delete each of its elements in turn. Also only delete them if they are owned by the current object(this is not apparent from your code).

I would create a helper private function `destroy` and re-use it in the assignment operator and in the destructor to avoid code duplication.